# How should I create two object to do two different ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                 

xhr.onload = function() {                    

  if(xhr.status === 200) {                     
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; // Update
  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'data/data-one.html', true);        // Prepare the request
xhr.send(null);
```

Now I want to do the same thing for another link, so when the link is clicked, in the code above, `data-one.html` is inserted to the HTML container with an id of content in my html page.

Now lets image I have another link in my nav and want to do the same process for another html container with an id of **content1** this time to insert **data-two.html** .

Do I have to create the httprequest in this file or another ajax file? Are the variables gonna be different?

I already tried with the same variable both in the same file and other files but I get an error saying the I can't set the innerHTML to Null. I can't find out why. Please help.

Comment: So your real issue is that some code is failing to return an element when you fetch it.

Comment: Do you want a pure JavaScript-answer? Or is jQuery ok?

Comment: Do you know how to make a function? It's really just as simple as that. As to the error you get, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question of making 2 AJAX requests.

Comment: please see the most updated version here: i still have some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990555/getting-the-first-data-html-instead-of-the-second-one-why

Answer (score 1):

This code is just to get you started. It is very verbose and can be improved to reused. For the sake of clarity I decided to keep it simple though.

```
function reqListener1 () {      
  console.log("listener1 -- html echo", this.responseText);
}

function reqListener2 () {
  console.log("listener2 -- json echo", this.responseText);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var url1 = "/echo/html/";
    var url2 = "/echo/json/";

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener1);
    oReq.open("GET", url1);
    oReq.send();

    // you could use the same variable. but you'll need to instantiate a different object
    var oReq2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq2.addEventListener("load", reqListener2);
    oReq2.open("GET", url2);
    oReq2.send();        
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pottersky/7dz8r19d/1/

Comment: please see the following:   i still have some problem i can't solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990555/getting-the-first-data-html-instead-of-the-second-one-why